# Fatal error: Array callback has to contain indices 0 and 1

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Array callback has to contain indices 0 and 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpprojects\plapp\worker.php on line 53

How can I solve that problem? What's wrong with what I am doing here?

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT asin_link FROM work WHERE email=$w_email");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $work_link = $row['asin_link'];
      echo '<a href="'.$work_link.'" target="'.$work_link.'">Visit Work link<br></a>';
      echo '<form action="" method="post">
        ASIN Number: <input type="text" name="asin"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
      </form>';}
      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $asin = $_POST('asin');
        $qu ="INSERT INTO work (asin, email, asin_link) VALUES ('$asin', '$w_email','$work_link')";
        if (mysql_query($qu)) {
        echo "Your ASIN was received! Thanks";
      }
      }
```

Answer (score 56):

change this

```
$asin = $_POST('asin');
```

to

```
$asin = $_POST['asin'];
```

Comment: yes you are right but asin_link value is not inserting to database. another 2 value is inserting successfully.

Comment: i laughed very hard when i noticed this lol thanks man its been a head ache for me

Comment: That moment when you've been a PHP developer for 10 years, but this answer helped you.

Comment: I just made this syntax mistake and tried to get the result but was stuck on it with confidence that I write the right code but here is what I got as an answer. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because your code tried to call an array as a function.
(That's why the error calls it **Array Callback**)

I know it's really late for any answers on this, but for anyone else coming from Googling this error and seeking more info I post this example of alternative syntax, it seems to run PHP >= 7 :

```
<?php
    class A {
        static function ech($a) {echo $a;}
        function echa($a) {echo $a;}
    }
    ['A', 'ech']('Test');
    [new A, 'echa']('Test');
```

Yes, it seems **arrays can be called as functions**.