# PHP Background color change

Tags: php, html, colors, background

i have an error with this code.
I want to change the background with the radio buttons, some help pls

```
<?php 
    if (!empty($_GET)) {
        if ($_GET('kleur') == 'rood') {
            echo  '<body bgcolor="red">';
        }
        if ($_GET('kleur') == 'oranje') {
            echo  '<body bgcolor="orange">';
        }
        if ($_GET('kleur') == 'geel') {
            echo  '<body bgcolor="yellow">';
        }
        if ($_GET('kleur') == 'groen') {
            echo  '<body bgcolor="green">';
        }
        if ($_GET('kleur') == 'blauw') {
            echo  '<body bgcolor="blue">';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: what is the error saying?

Comment: Stop using `bgcolor` attribute. It's 2016 now. Use CSS instead. Also, there is obvious syntax error in PHP `$GET['kleur']` not `$_GET('kleur')`

Comment: Unrelated to your question: you should really code everything in English, it is the default language ;)

Comment: Fatal error: Array callback has to contain indices 0 and 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\seb1.php on line 7

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370443/fatal-error-array-callback-has-to-contain-indices-0-and-1

Answer (score 1):

Write a clean code.
Define array of possible colors:

```
$colorMap = [
    'rood' => 'red',
    'oranje' => 'orange',
    'geel' => 'yellow',
    'groen' => 'green',
    'blauw' => 'blue'
];
```

And get color which you need (instead of `DEFAULT_COLOR` set default color):

```
if (isset($_GET['kleur']) && isset($colorMap[$_GET['kleur']])) {
    $bgColor = $colorMap[$_GET['kleur']];
} else {
    $bgColor = DEFAULT_COLOR
}
```

Than output your html:

```
echo '<body style="background-color: '.$bgColor.'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have php syntax error

> Here you are using if (**$_GET('kleur')** == 'rood') {

which is wrong it should be **$_GET['kleur']**

Make sure you do it in all your conditions.
for more on $_GET function [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score 0):

replace this,

```
if ($_GET('kleur') == 'blauw')
```

to

```
if ($_GET['kleur'] == 'blauw')
```

Answer (score 0):

On your page body style you need to have a style attribute that will change based on clicked radio. and the easy way is to use switch.

```
    <body style="<?php echo $body_style;?>">


    </body>

<?php
$body_style=""; // so that we don't get undifined index on body style

    if(isset($_GET['kleur'])){

        switch ($_GET['kleur']) {
        case 'rood':

            $body_style = "background:red";

            break;

        case 'oranje':
            $body_style = "background:orange"
            break;

        case 'geel':
            $body_style ="background:yellow";
            break;

        case 'groen':
             $body_style="background:green"
            break;

        case 'blauw':
                $body_style="background:blue"
                break;
        default:
            $body_style="";
            break;
    }


    }


?>
```