# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Array callback must have exactly two elements

Tags: php

I tried a lot but it, again and again, showing same error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Array callback must have exactly two elements",

error is showing on line no.2

```
if($_SERVER(['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')){
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: Also, ALWAYS show us ALL the error message. Thay normally come with more information than that and ALL of it can be useful

Comment: **Never** store passwords in the database as Plain Text. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: `$_SERVER(['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` is not a function so code as `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370443/fatal-error-array-callback-has-to-contain-indices-0-and-1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$_SERVER` is not a function, its an array, you need to remove `()` after `$_SERVER`, and your code will look like below

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ ... }
```

PS: as everyone said , your script is open to SQL Injection Attack and Never store passwords in the database as Plain Text. Please follow the guidelines on the comments

Comment: Completely missed that. But this makes it a TYPO and we dont answer those. we make a comment and then close the question

Comment: Cant count this in a typo, using an `array `as a `function` is generally a conceptual fault rather than a typo. A typo would have been an unclosed brackets etc