# how to take filename from previous page using php

Tags: php

I am creating a access log in PHP where I am storing the logged-in username , userip and userlogged-in time inside my sql server database

I want to add one more field filename into that, I am taking everything from previous pages using sessions but however, I am unable to figure out how do I  take filename from the previous page

I am sharing my code too. Any help would be highly appreciated.

my code for creating access log in php and storing it inside sql-server database is

```
 session_start();
 include 'database_connection.php'
 $uname = $_SESSION["user"] ;
 echo $uname;
 
 function getUserIP()
 {
     // Get real visitor IP behind CloudFlare network
     if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])) {
               $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
               $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
     }
     $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
     $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
     $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 
     if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
     {
         $ip = $client;
     }
     elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
     {
         $ip = $forward;
     }
     else
     {
         $ip = $remote;
     }
 
     return $ip;
 }
 $user_ip = getUserIP();
 
 echo $user_ip; // Output IP address [Ex: 177.87.193.134]
 
 $currentDate = date('Y-m-d g:i:s');
 
 echo $currentDate;
 
 
 $sql = "insert into ACCESS_LOGOFUSERS(ALU_USERNAME,ALU_IP,ALU_CREATEDON)
 VALUES('$uname','$user_ip','$currentDate')";
 
 $res = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
 
 session_destroy();
 
  ?>
```

my file name code which is stored on the previous page is

```
 $fileName = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

I am unable to figure out how shall I take the $filename to another page with the help of the session so that I can also add the below code to my existing code

```
  $query=sqlsrv_query("insert into user_action(file_name)values('$file_name')");
```

Comment: Why, where is the problem? Stick the value into a session variable, `$_SESSION['fileToUpload'] = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);` or something like that, and then access it via that in the following script.

Comment: @CBroe $FileName =  $_SESSION['fileToUpload'] = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

echo $FileName;
 I  have used this and I am getting undefined error session is started on every page

Comment: What error (_exactly_), and referring to what line? It is hard to tell what the issue is, when you show single lines of code out of context.

Comment: @CBroe This line is only causing error $FileName = $_SESSION['fileToUpload'] = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);  even-though session is started on every page

Comment: `$FileName = $_SESSION['fileToUpload'] =` are assignments, not _read_ access. So any error saying something was undefined, could only come from the `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]` part here.

Comment: @CBroe How to $_SESSION WITH $_FILES

Comment: Storing a value into the session always works the same way, no matter where that value came from. If the error message is relating to `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]`(I asked you to tell us the _exact_ error), then you need to figure out why that is not set at the point where you are trying to do this.

Comment: @CBroe whenever i am using $fileName = $_Session(basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])) ;  I am getting syntax error

Comment: How many more times do I need to say, please give us the _exact_ error. (And that line in itself does _not_ contain a syntax error, so it probably must be something before that then.)

Comment: @CBroe i am getting this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Array callback must have exactly two elements on this line $fileName  = $_SESSION(basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));

Comment: $_SESSION is an array, but you are trying to call a function here. Array access uses _square_ brackets.

Comment: But even with square brackets, using `basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])` as the array key, makes little sense. You won't _know_ what that value actually is, on your second page - so how could you _use_ that value then, to access the session entry?

Comment: @CBroe even after using square bracket i am getting same error

Comment: Show the modified code, otherwise there is no way of telling what you might have misunderstood this time.

Comment: @CBroe This time i have used this code $fileName  = $_SESSION[basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])];

Comment: I don't see how that could possibly get you the same error. And as I already said, using that value as the session _key_ here, does not make much sense to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe  Uncaught Error: Array callback must have exactly two elements in i am getting this error

Comment: The error makes sense, as long as you used the wrong type of braces - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/71450130/1427878 But you say you fixed that now, so it makes no sense that you would still get that same error (at least not from the same place in the code) - and https://3v4l.org/tSVdl also shows nothing of the sort. (It shows a couple of other errors because the data is not set, but if the code you have shown actually caused a fatal error, that should happen in there as well.)

Comment: @CBroe I am not getting where exactly I am getting the error

Comment: Why not, the error message should contain file name and line number?

Comment: @CBroe Is this code correct ? $fileName  = $_SESSION[basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])];

Comment: Syntactically, on its own - yes. But does it make sense ... No. And I already said why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248929/discussion-between-veronica-dsouza-and-cbroe).